# How to find formula from a table?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, output-formatting, list-manipulation, combinatorics

I recently started using mathematica for simple tasks like simplifying etc.

[image: Table of values]

First of all let me say if this breaks any rules I apologize since I'm a novice in using this and I'll remove the question.

I want to use the table of values above to find a  **GENERAL FORMULA** that represents the values.

What I want to achieve is a function in terms of '$V$' such that for any value of '$V$' I enter I will get the corresponding '$SS$' value.

In simple terms I'm looking for an equation such that when '$V$' is equal to '6' say, then I can input this into an equation which would probably look something like $D_{5}$ [Since it's the sum of the first 5 terms]= equation in terms of $V$ = $SS$ value.

But I need this equation to hold for an value of $V$ in the entire table.

The formula can also use the $E$ value I just thought it would be easier to study with respect to $V$.

I know there's the FindFormula operator but i'm not sure how to incoperate this with the table to solve such a problem.

Comment: The first step would be plotting the data.  But with only 4 data points there's not much you can do for which you could be confident in future predictions.  You might consider the following:  `v = {6, 9, 12, 15}; ss = {29, 84, 178, 320}; ListLogLogPlot[Transpose[{v, ss}]]` followed by `lm = LinearModelFit[Log[Transpose[{v, ss}]], x, x]`.

Comment: What is the meanings of rows and colums in your table?

Comment: @JimB If I were to calculate more $SS$ values(Which I can) Is it possible to get a better more suited general formula? And how would I do such. Thanks

Comment: @MustafaKösem The Rows and Columns correspond to a vertex and edge of a random graph in which I used a method to find the SS values. I am currently doing some research in different nanostar calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[n_]:=2*(3n+6-1)(n+2)+Total[9Table[Binomial[n,j]+n,{j,0,n}] ]
f[0]
f[1]
f[2]
f[3]
```

> 29
> 84
> 178
> 320

Also here is the hole Table:

```
Table[Flatten[Riffle[Table[{3n+6-1,3n+6-1},n+2],9Table[Binomial[n,j]+n,{j,0,n} ]]],{n,0,3}]
```

> {{5,5,9,5,5},{8,8,18,8,8,18,8,8},{11,11,27,11,11,36,11,11,27,11,11},{14,14,36,14,14,54,14,14,54,14,14,36,14,14}}

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you arrived at `2*(3n+6-1)(n+2)`? This seems to be the crux of the formula. 

I'm inquiring because if i calculate different nanostar graphs my table rows and columns will change and the number of values etc. Is there a blueprint that I can use to change accordingly? Thank you.

Comment: That formula is the easy part... it just calculates the n-1 values for the initial values of V={6,9,12,15...} but it works for 0,1,2,3.... What values exactly do you need to know? The formula works for any n, and so does the table.

Comment: @JasonMoore the above formula generates the SS values that you want `{29,84,178,320,528,838,1322,2124,3532,6122,11046....}`. It doesn't really matter if you use `{0,1,2,3,....)` or `6+3n` for `n={0,1,2,3}` (which is the V column) or `5+3n` (which is the E column). The tricky part is to calculate the values {...,36,...,54,.....,54,,,,36} which come from `Binomial[n,k]+n`

Comment: Can you indulge me a bit further if possible.  
What changes would I have to make to this table [https://imgur.com/FodLUQF] to have the same type of outputs.  

Yes , the values are indeed different , however the $V$ and $E$ columns follow the same $n-1$ pattern as before but the above formula will not hold for this table.

Can you please advise me on what tools specifically that I would have to master , or look at , to be able to manipulate the code to any such table? Thank you @J42161217

Comment: [Imgur]https://imgur.com/gallery/ffNlsdQ Backup link of image incase it's taken down.

Comment: @JasonMoore It's like a puzzle... Firstly, learn Pascal's Triangle and how to produce it using Binomial. Then you must learn to recognize patterns... here is your table: `Table[Join[{k+5,k+5},If[k==0,{9},Accumulate[Join[{(k+3)3},Table[-2 m,{j,0,2,1/2},{m,-j,j}][[k]]]]],{k+5,k+5}],{k,0,5}]` If you want the sums of each row add `Total/@` in the beginning of the code and you'll get `{29,48,74,108,151,204}`